# BASH: shellcheck warning SC2178 for declare -n

Tags: bash, local, declare, shellcheck

New to shellcheck here.  See pseudocode and error below.

```
#!/bin/bash
function throwAwayFunc() {
        local _array=();
}

function arraysFromArray() {
  local i _id; _id=$1;
  declare -n _array="${_id}";
#               ***^-- SC2178 (warning): Variable was used as an array but is now assigned a string.***
  for i in "${_array[@]}"; do
    makeArr "$i";
  done;
}
```

Edited to clarify context:
I am, indeed, expecting an array here.  Am I doing this wrong?
My point here is that the declare -n here is, at worst, ambiguous, and yet, this is the error. So, can I ignore this?

Comment: Do you need the `_id` variable? `local -n _array=$1`

Comment: This seems to be fixed in the most recent ShellCheck. What version do you use?

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, this is just a sample function.  In a lot of cases, I do need the name of the array I'm working with.  And, of course, it gripes if I use a direct assignment as well, so, not sure how to get around that.

Comment: @BenjaminW.Using the website directly for this.  Someone else pointed me to it in an earlier post.

Comment: I put a shebang line before the code in the question and copied it into [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).  The only warning was about the unused variable `i`.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE).

Comment: Are you calling this function from another function where you also use the `_id` variable?

Comment: @glennjackman I've provided some clarification above here.  This is part of a larger array wrapper package I put together to make other aspects of my code less complex (namely, pretending that there's such a thing as multi-dimensional arrays in bash).  In any case, the point here is that I am, in fact, declaring an array here by way of name-ref which is the point, I think, of declare -n.  What I'm wondering is whether the parser just doesn't relate to it that way or if there is something going on under the hood that I should know about.

Comment: Check the wiki page for this one: https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2178 -- there is a known bug